# Find Largest Value of Range With Criteria and Return Value of Another Cell

Tags: excel, worksheet-function

I need to figure out the formula to get last messageis based on memberid within a threadid.

Below is an example. Basically the first instance of a memberid within a threadid I need to return the value of messageid in "Last Post ID"

I have a database with tens of thousands of messageid and threadid, so I can't do it manually like I did below. I'm not sure how to set up a forumla or macro to perform this task. Any help is appreciated.

```
messageid   threadid    memberid    # of Posts By ID        Last Post ID        
4332        3304        39          1                       4332        
4678        3304        231         1                       4678        
5383        3304        363         16                      5383        
5289        3304        363         15              
5240        3304        363         14              
5082        3304        363         13              
4990        3304        363         12              
4479        3304        363         11              
4478        3304        363         10              
4477        3304        363         9               
4330        3304        363         8               
4329        3304        363         7               
3944        3304        363         6               
3732        3304        363         5               
3730        3304        363         4               
3446        3304        363         3               
3396        3304        363         2               
3304        3304        363         1               
4343        3304        436         4                       4343        
4185        3304        436         3               
3816        3304        436         2               
3696        3304        436         1               
5010        3304        504         1                       5010        
5946        3304        522         1                       5946        
5409        3304        533         9                       5409        
5302        3304        533         8               
5260        3304        533         7               
5215        3304        533         6               
4362        3304        533         5               
3804        3304        533         4               
3471        3304        533         3               
3403        3304        533         2               
3342        3304        533         1               
3682        3304        821         1                       3682        
4151        3304        984         1                       4151        
3751        3304        1184        1                       3751        
5790        3304        1350        1                       5790        
5399        3304        1509        1                       5399        
7199        3304        2042        1                       7199
```

Comment: Is it always sorted like the example?

Comment: Yes, I can always make it that sorting. I sort by threadid, then by memberid then messageid (descending).

Comment: Then a simple in E2 `=IF(D2<>D1,A2,"")`

Comment: Sorry got my column messed up: `=IF(C2<>C1,A2,"")`